# MongoError: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial, 2dsphere, database

I am attempting to use MongoDB's Geospatial Indexing by querying for latitude and longitude points around a certain point using MongoDB's find method. I keep getting the error:

> MongoError: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index)

I'm not sure where the documentation is for this after Googling for about an hour. Also I can't find any good explanations. Here is the Schema that I created using Mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var EventSchema = new Schema ({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  location: {type: [String], index: '2dsphere'},
  time: Date,
  photo: Buffer,
  activity: String
});

mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

I then use the *find* method to find other *Event* documents around the point that the user provides.

```
var maxDistance = 0.09;
var lonLat = {$geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [34.09,124.34] }};

Event.find({
  'geo': {
    $near: lonLat,
    $maxDistance: maxDistance
  }
}).exec(function(err, events) {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    return events;
  }
});
```

What syntax do I have wrong here? Am I missing something huge? Any urls to any documentation will be great as well besides [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/).

Comment: did you actually make the indexes? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/ quic search for mongodb 2d indexes

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to create the index with this sentence?

> db.event.ensureIndex({ "location" : "2d" } )

It's a little confusing your example. I don't get if 'location' are your coordinates or 'geo', because you create the schema with the former and you query with the latter.

In both cases, a good idea is to execute

> db.event.findOne().pretty()

So you can check the format of your collection.

Also with this command you can check your current indexes.

> db.event.getIndexes()

All of this works if you are working on 'event' collection.